# Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM

Tags: build

When building using the autobuild script, I encountered the following error:

CMake Error at libraries/wasm-jit/Source/Runtime/CMakeLists.txt:26 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" (requested
  version 4.0) with any of the following names:

```
LLVMConfig.cmake
llvm-config.cmake
```

Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.

LLVM wasn't previously installed and all the dependencies were successfully installed via the build script. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your OS, but with `brew`

```
$ brew info llvm  
llvm: stable 4.0.0 (bottled), HEAD [keg-only]
```

And let cmake know where to find cmake files for llvm:

```
export LLVM_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/lib/cmake
```

Similar path to `llvm/4.0/lib/cmake` should exist for macports or installation from source.
For permanent change add it to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`